# logrorate: error: lines must begin with a keyword or a filename (possibly in double quotes)

Tags: ubuntu, logrotate

I have the following logrorate config for my iptables:

```
/var/log/iptables.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 3
        compress
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        postrotate
        /usr/sbin/service rsynclog restart > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

When I try to issue checking for file syntax I the following error:

```
sudo logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.d/iptables

reading config file iptables
reading config info for /var/log/iptables.log 
error: iptables:1 lines must begin with a keyword or a filename (possibly in double quotes)
```

What's wrong in my config file?

Comment: Any strange file encoding maybe? What do you get from `file /etc/logrotate.d/iptables` for example?

Comment: check the line breaks in the file. They should be LF (not CRLF). You should remove carriage returns.

Comment: @birgire buy using your command I get: /etc/logrotate.d/iptables: ASCII text, with CR line terminators

Comment: I've only `ASCII text` on mine, so the Carrige Returns (CR) are most likely your problem. You should save your file in Unix format. Do you write your file in Windows?

Answer (score 18):

You should be able to save your file in a `Unix` format in your editor.

If you want to solve this from the terminal, there are lot's of suggestions here:

https://superuser.com/questions/52044/convert-crlfs-to-line-feeds-on-linux
https://superuser.com/questions/156516/is-there-a-bash-command-to-convert-r-n-to-n
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/

You can for example try this one:

```
dos2unix -b /etc/logrotate.d/iptables
```

where `-b` stands for *backup*.

Or create a backup yourself:

```
cp /etc/logrotate.d/iptables /etc/logrotate.d/iptables.bak
```

and then try:

```
tr -d '\r' < /etc/logrotate.d/iptables > /etc/logrotate.d/iptables
```

There are lot's of other suggestions in the links above.

Comment: In Sublime it's View -> Line Endings.

Answer (score 7):

Replace CR line terminators by LF

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/

Comment: You are right! My config file is copy from windows to linux, the newline format are different.